# necesito ayuda en un ejercicio de C

Tags: c

este es el enunciado si podrian ayudarme de verdad agradeceria mucho:

SE REQUIERE UN ALGORITMO PARA DETERMINAR CUÁNTO AHORRARÁ EN PESOS UNA PERSONA DIARIAMENTE, Y EN UN AÑO, SI AHORRA 3¢ EL PRIMERO DE ENERO, 9¢ EL DOS DE ENERO, 27¢ EL 3 DE ENERO Y ASÍ SUCESIVAMENTE TODO EL AÑO.

Comment: ¿en qué parte ocupas ayuda, qué llevas hecho, cuáles fallos has tenido?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: hola amigo. la verdad es que en la logica para hacerlo ya que no entiendo muy bien el enunciado para comenzar a programar el algoritmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta es muy mala. No puedes pretender que te resolvamos un ejercicio completo sin haber intentado nada.

A la hora de comprender esto, intenta plantearlo como un ejercicio matemático. Fíjate en lo siguiente:

> AHORRA 3¢ EL PRIMERO DE ENERO, 9¢ EL DOS DE ENERO, 27¢ EL 3 DE ENERO Y ASÍ SUCESIVAMENTE TODO EL AÑO

Esto quiere decir que si `i`es la iteración por al que va (el día), cada nuevo día va a ahorrar

`(i-1)*3`

Con el caso base del primero que es `3`. 
Es decir:

```
primera=3
3*3=9
9*3=27
27*3=81
81*3=243
...
```

El algoritmo que te piden es bastante sencillo. Cogerel resultado de esa iteración y usarlo como primer dato en la siguiente. El resultado `9`es el dato de la siguiente.

Con esto deberías tener para poder empezar. Cualquier duda, puedes preguntar una nueva pregunta, esta vez con lo que has intentado.

Comment: gracias amigo, lo que no entendia era como hacer ese (i-1)*3 ya que no le conseguia logica para comenzarlo, estoy iniciando en esto de la programacion y aun no tengo tanta habilidad en esto, muchas gracias

Comment: No hay problema! Gracias a ti! @Dureymon